# Why can't I run APK files on Windows?

Tags: java, android, windows, apk

I have read book as below because of programming studying

"When you install the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) on your operating system, programs written in Java will work exactly the same on any computer. Virtual machines are built for each operating system so that they run exactly the same."

I know just window is x86, Andoroid is ARM system.
But APK file is made by Java language. And maybe there is JVM on my window computer.
Why I cannot run on my window PC?

(Android system does not use JVM. it uses Android Runtime (VM) . this is root cause?)

Comment: There are many tutorials around the web that can help you with that. Basically you need java on your pc and an android emulator.

Comment: actually, this is interesting question. Why one needs an emulator?

Comment: I don't think APK is a java package format. As far as I know, it could also contain native code on Android. It's not supposed to run on another OS like windows without an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

An APK is basically a zip package containing an application compiled for the Android Runtime, not for a JVM running on Windows. You need to use an Android emulator to be able to run Android apps on Windows. Genymotion is one of them:

https://www.genymotion.com

But there are many available if you search on Google.

Comment: He asks why not how